# Kerning irregularities in ggtext markdown titles

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, ggtext

I keep generating irregularities in kerning when using `ggtext` for `ggplot` titles.

For instance:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(showtext)
library(ggtext)

font_add_google("Public Sans")

p1 <- mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      wt, mpg
    )
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Public Sans") +
  labs(
    title =  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel vel est donec nulla nam aliquet in in auctor. Sed dolor orci aliquet nunc" 
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_markdown()
  )

showtext_auto()
ggsave(
  plot = p1,
  filename = "mtcars plot.pdf",
  width = 11.3,
  height = 4.5
)
```

generates a plot like this (red highlighting added to show the kerning irregularities.)

[image]

Is this a known bug or am I misusing this library?

Comment: I get a ton of warnings and no text when I use `base_family = "Public Sans"`.  When I use `base_family="Helvetica"` or just leave out the `theme_minimal()` call, things look fine.

Comment: Renders fine on my Mac: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4drv.png. But I remember that there was a somewhat related [issue](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext/issues/81) in the past which however should be fixed if you use the most recent versions of ggtext and (!!) gridtext. For reference I'm using ggtext 0.1.2 and gridtext 0.1.5 (and ggplot2 3.4.4).

Comment: @stefan: interesting. on Windows the fault is apparent even with current versions of `ggtext`, `gridtext`, and `ggplot2`.